# Internationalization of text data using Apache POI for Excel Import export

Tags: internationalization, apache-poi

I work in Java Technology and a beginner in Apache POI. I am implementing Excel Import Export using Apache POI API and data in mysql database. I have to read and write the localized data Like Chinese characters and other characters that are UTF-8  / UTF-16 encoded. For eg, the Titles in the Excel will be localized but data can be in English.
 I want to know, if POI provides API to write into the Excel that takes encoding as parameter or some other way. Pls suggest.

The API that i know is : workbook.write(fileoutputstream). Please suggest if there is a way to write other encoding characters.

Thanks in advance,
Pallavi

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI works with Java Strings. Java Strings are unicode - see the [official Java Strings and Bytes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) for more if this is all new to you.

As long as you give POI a valid Java string for your character, it will save that into the file for you. However, you do need to ensure you get the strings into your program correctly!

POI has loads of unit tests which verify it handles unicode characters just fine, take a look at [TestBugs](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/testcases/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/TestBugs.java) for quite a few

Comment: Apache POI may handle Java Strings without a problem, but it doesn't mean that Excel file will be correctly encoded. The problem is, the old Office format is ***not*** Unicode-enabled, but code page based.

Comment: The older OLE2 formats generally support two different kinds of strings, one 8 bit codepage based, one unicode based. POI knows this, and knows when to switch between the two for you. Take a look at the unit tests, or just try it!

Comment: I am still not clear with the solution you mentioned.

Comment: You meant, we can store the unicode characters in a String varible and the same can be used to write into the Excel. For eg.- I have a String with value String chineseChar ="您好遊客" , which I am getting from database. That I will itself write to a file. I think this will work, I shall check this. Thanks for information.